# Laravel Query builder condition with current query using when

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, conditional-statements, laravel-query-builder

How can I create a condition using current query with laravel query builder, is it even possible, i guess it would look something like this

```
$record = $this->repository
   ->where('value', $value)
   ->when($thisQuery->get()->isNotEmpty(), static function(){
    //execute
    });
```

Comment: How would the SQL query look like? You are asking to get the result of a query before running the query, it is confusing

Comment: I was thinking could i get current value after where(), to check if its not empty for condition, i could search and the use a if statment, just curious if its possible with something like that :)

Comment: You will indeed have to do it in 2 steps as you mentioned with 2 different queries

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheHubert, I'll look into this or a subquery then :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use sub-queries in anonymous function as in the example below:

```
 $record = $this->repository
            ->where('value', $value)
            ->where(function($query) {
                /** @var $query Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder  */
                return $query->where('foo', 'LIKE', '%foooo%')
                             ->orWhere('foo', 'bar');
            })
            ->get();
```

You can as well run multiple where clauses as in the following:

```
 $record = $this->repository
            ->where('value', $value)
            ->where('foo', 'bar')
            ->get();
```

And depends on the `requirements` use the appropriate way.